# Bootstrapping a bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

One of the criticisms of using a bootstrap procedure is that the results are not reproducible in the sense that you may come to a different conclusions when you re-run the bootstrap analysis again.

This happened to me today. I was trying to bootstrap a difference in means and found that I would not reject then null hypothesis using 1000 bootstrap samples. The next time I ran this procedure, I rejected the null hypothesis. So, I got the idea to bootstrap my bootstrap estimates. I found that in 1000 samples, I would reject the null hypothesis 959/1000 times. My interpretation, is that I can be fairly confident that I can reject the null hypothesis. Does this seem like a reasonable approach? If so, is there any literature to support this?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you describe what you mean exactly by "using 1000 bootstrap samples" ? It looks to me as if you're not bootstrapping, but rather sub-sampling from a large dataset.

Comment: You are correct. I sampled with replacement from my original sample 1000 times. I then calculated the proportion of samples in which my original mean difference was greater than the sampled mean difference. Thus resulting in an approximate p-value for my test statistic (i.e., mean difference). I then repeated this procedure 1000 times to see what proportion of the time I would reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: An example of bootstrapping the bootstrap is in the last chapter of Statistical Models: Theory and Practice, Friedman. http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Models-Practice-David-Freedman/dp/0521743850 If you don't have this book, you probably can find it in any reasonable statistics library.

Comment: Shouldn't the first round of bootstrapping use reasonably many bootstrap samples so you could be reasonably confident that the bootstrap result is not due to chance? If 1000 first-round samples is not enough, what about trying more than that? You could perhaps calculate the number of bootstrap samples needed to achieve a desired confidence level before you start the whole thing. Disclaimer: I am a newbie at bootstrap, so do not take my opinion too seriously.

Comment: I have a problem with "One of the criticisms of using a bootstrap procedure is that the results are not reproducible in the sense that you may come to a different conclusions when you re-run the bootstrap analysis again." -- after a number of bootstrap samples (say, 10^5), your results should be stable. And they can be reproducible if you set a seed.

Answer (score 3):

If your sample is such that bootstrap replicates are giving you conflicting answers it means you're Monte Carlo error is too large.  Remember that there is a true bootstrap answer represented by taking all possible resamples.  Since it is impractical to do this usually we do Monte Carlo approximation.  So, its not that  the bootstrap is really giving you a conflict, its just that your decision limit is within your MC error... take more resamples.

Answer (score 3):

As others suggested, your should rather increase the number of bootstrap replications. Notice that your idea, to "bootstrap the bootstrap" is in fact increasing the number of replications, since you want to sample, for example, 1000 bootstrap replications 1000 times, so in the end you are going to take the one million samples. Why not *just* take one million samples? Taking the samples in groups and "all at once" leads to basically the same outcome, but aggregated differently.

Second thing to notice is that the number of bootstrap replications should be planned considering your needs and bootstrap errors, as already noticed by others in comments.

In your case, if you want to to conduct some kind of hypothesis test, say on 1% level of significance, this means that you want to see the outcome considered as your alternative hypothesis in ten out of thousand samples; I'd say that this is *not* that much. What is you draw twelve such samples? If you want to sample something that extreme, you'd need to draw much more bootstrap replications. One thousand is a nice round number, but it's not big for bootstrap.

Comment: There are such things as nested , double or iterated bootstrap.  You can find out about these things in books like Efron and Tibshirani, or Davison and Hinkley or my book Bootstrap Methods.   These methods are used as ways to construct better confidence intervals or error rates in discriminant analysis.  These iterated bootstraps can be computer-intensive.  Since you are looking for differences in means iterated bootstrap may not apply.  It matter where your data comes from.  We need the bootstrap estimates to be consistent which need not always be the case.